# Non-https links to other StackExchange sites in User profile when using https

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, security

The links to other StackExchange sites in User profile -> Summary -> Accounts don't use https when the User profile was accessed using https.

Comment: Full HTTPS support has not been rolled out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support HTTPS by default yet.  You would get mixed content warnings on many, *many* pages right now - so we don't link to or force `https://` yet.  The page is behaving as it should.